# Symfony2 notice: Array to string conversion in Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I'm using **Sonata admin** on **Symfony 2.1.3**. Now trying to add text input with google map.

Added line in `configureFormFields()` function:

```
->add('coordinates', 'contentbundle_coordinates_map', array('required' => false,'attr'=>array('class'=>'mapCoordinate')))
```

registred in services and created template for this:

```
{% block contentbundle_coordinates_map_widget %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/add.scripts.js') }}"></script>
    <input type="text" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
    <div id="add_map" class="map" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Can see my field with map in admin content add page, but when I want to submit data getting:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\my_vendor_folder\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php line 103
```

If I change **contentbundle_coordinates_map** with **null**:

```
->add('coordinates', null, array('required' => false,'attr'=>array('class'=>'mapCoordinate')))
```

everything works.

Where is the problem?

**UPDATE**

Form Type Class:

```
namespace Map\ContentBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CoordinatesMapType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contentbundle_coordinates_map';
    }
}
```

Comment: We'll probably need to be able to see your Form Type for `contentbundle_coordinates_map`. My first guess would be that its `getParent()` method isn't returning the correct type.

Comment: @RobMasters updated question with Form Type. You'r right, I even have no getParent method. Could you please tell me what it need to returns? And plese write it like answer so I can mark it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always define the `getParent` method for custom Form Types in order to inherit the logic of that particular type. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html) for a list of types.

In this case, it looks as though your custom type should be returning text, so add the following to `CoordinatesMapType`:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'text';
}
```

As an alternative, if you only need to customise the rendering of the form field then you don't even need to create your own custom form type. See [How to customize an Individual field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field). I think this would only be possible though if you've manually given your form a name. (assuming it's name is "content")

```
{# This is in the view where you're rendering the form #}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _content_coordinates_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/add.scripts.js') }}"></script>
        <input type="text" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
        <div id="add_map" class="map" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In this case, you'd specify the type as `null`, as in your 2nd example:

```
->add('coordinates', null, array('required' => false,'attr'=>array('class'=>'mapCoordinate')))
```